# Java: Calculate the number of nights between two LocalDateTime objects

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to write a function to calculate the number of nights between two LocalDateTime objects in Java.

This is what I've come up with so far (using `java.time.LocalDateTime`):

```
    //Test LocalDateTime objects
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(5).plusHours(3);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();

    long days = Duration.between(start, end).toDays();
    int nightCount = (int) days;
    if (end.toLocalTime().isBefore(start.toLocalTime())) {
        ++nightCount;
    }
```

This seems to do the job but I'm aware DateTime can cause all sorts of problems related to timezone, daylight savings etc.

Can anyone propose a better function?

Comment: How do you define a night? If the start and end times are both in the daytime, I think the expected answer is clear. But what if one of them is at nighttime?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to be using here. `ZonedDateTime` is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the time part completely, and use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between`:

```
int nights = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate());
```

This works because by `toLocalDate`, you are considering only the *date* part of the local date times.

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to work well. I understand the difference between Period and Duration, but I'm wondering why Duration.between(start, end).toDays(); behaves differently to your code. It's as if Period rounds up the days, and duration rounds down when you covert it using .toDays(). Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: @Ben123 That suggests to me that you haven't understood the difference between `Period` and `Duration`. `Period` works on _date_ components, whereas `Duration` works on _time_ components. `toDays` simply counts how many 24 hours there are in the duration. `Period` on the other hand, looks at the _dates_ only (Note how it accepts a `LocalDate` instead of `TemporalAccessor` like `Duration` does) and calculates the difference in years, months and days.